# Contiuous updating Django for standalone app

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

**What I want to do**

I am trying to build an app that will be used on a single computer and only as a stand-alone non-web app. I am just using HTML for the user interface. I would like to continually update a value by rerunning the get_context_data and have it appear on the website as the newly produced value. Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
class HomePage(TemplateView):
    template_name = "index.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['number'] = random.randomrange(1,100)
        return context
```

Which I add to the index page as follows:

```
<h2>Welcome to site {{ number }}</h2>
```

Which shows up as:

[image]

I would like to update that random number at regular intervals. I could just refresh the page but this would cause the side menu to go back to its default extended state at each page refresh which I do not want.

**The Question**

Can someone provide me an example of the simplest way to implement such a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to update that number on the page and not the whole page, then making a background ajax request is going to be the best approach.

This doesn't have to be too complicated. Using [JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) makes it pretty straightforward. Here's a simple example.

In the template markup you'll need to be able to identify the site number, such as:

```
<span id="site_number">1</span>
```

The template will need to [include JQuery](https://code.jquery.com/) and should include a `JQuery.get()` call which repeatedly polls an end point:

```
$(function() {
    function pollSiteNumber() {
        $.get('/site_number/', function(resp) {
            $('#site_number').text(resp['site_number']);  // Update the value
        });
        window.setTimeout(pollSiteNumber, 60000);  // Repeat every minute
    }
    pollSiteNumber();
});
```

On the backend, you should define a view for `/site_number/` that returns  a `JsonResponse`.

```py
from django.http import JsonResponse

def get_site_number(request):
    data = {'site_number': random.randrange(1, 100)}
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

And wire that in to your `urls.py`:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('site_number/', get_site_number)
]
```

For Django Rest Framework, you would implement the view such as:

```py
from rest_framework import views
from rest_framework.response import Response

class SiteNumberView(views.APIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = {'site_number': random.randrange(1, 100)}
        return Response(data)
```

And `urls.py` (Django 1.11):

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns(
    ...
    url(r'^site_number/', SiteNumberView.as_view())
)
```

Comment: This is a great example. That being said, I have tried to implement what you gave me here with Django 1.11 and using Class Based Views and it is not going well (I am still quite new to this) 

`class APIView(CsrfExemptMixin,JsonRequestResponseMixin):
    def get_random_range():
        random_number = random.randint(1,100)
        return random_number

    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        data = {'site_number': str(self.get_random_range)}

        return self.render_json_response(data)` And I cannot use path in Django 1.11 so I get stuck there too... Any insight?

Comment: If you're using `APIView` from Django Rest Framework, the code is very similar except your view should implement the `get(self, request, *args, **kwargs)` method. I have updated my answer with that.